# Rails. How to put few controllers on one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Todo app now and I have troubles. After sign in, I am on persons profile(first controller), on it I have button for new project(projects controller-2d controller) and after pressing it, appears button for new tasks(task controller-3d controller). How I can put all of this 3 controller's views on one page. Here an example of what I mean(approximately):http://todo.kzotov.ru/

Answer (score 1):

You can put anything you want in the view. You could eager load the projects and tasks and put it all on the profile page. You also don't have to map controllers and views to models, so if the PersonsController or whatever is not what you're looking for, maybe do something more specific like ProfilesController and host all this functionality there.

Answer (score 1):

**MVC**

You'll be best reading up on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) -

[image]

The bottom line is that if you send a request to your application, it will only hit **one** `controller#action`. Your multiple "controllers" should not be something to consider - you should only look at the single controller action you're accessing at that specific time.

To be more specific about this, let me detail how it all works...

---

**OOP**

Ruby (on top of which Rails is a framework), is [object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This is not just a fancy phrase - it's a real pattern of programming, which allows you to focus the *flow* of your application around the data / objects you want to create. The *objects* in Rails are derived from your `Model`s - collating & organizing the respective data for your `controllers`

In order to understand how Rails works - you need to appreciate that *everything* you do is based on `objects`. Your routes, actions & data all work together to provide the end-user experience we know from Rails. How that happens is down to you.

Specifically, you want to look what *what* you're accessing

You don't want to load multiple *controllers* - you want to build several **models** and show those. This gives you the ability to show the HTML elements / files you want:

---

**Recommendation**

I would make sure you can put all your activity on your single view, which will then mean you have to determine your controller's data in order to provide you with the data you need to show:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      #your index
   end
end

#app/views/profile/index.html.erb
<%= link_to "task", task_path %>
```

What you'll probably want to do is create a separate route / method to give them the ability to pull back ajax data when the initial button was clicked. I can detail this if you need it, but what I've given you should be ample food for thought